# Getting EOF exception over https call

Tags: .net, http

My code making https request. This is my code

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(UploadUrl);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userid, testpwd);

            postData = "<root></root>";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            byte[] postDataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            request.ContentLength = postDataBytes.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
                var result = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                responseReader.Close();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
```

This code was running good but all of a sudden throwing following exception

> ```
> System.Net.WebException
> ```
>
> The exception message is:
>   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
>
> Stack Trace:    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) 
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()    at
>   CustomerProcessor.Delivery.Deliver(String content, Int32
>   productCategory, String identifier, String xsltFile)
>
> The Exception has an inner exception: An Exception occurred:
>   System.IO.IOException The exception message is: Received an unexpected
>   EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
>
> Stack Trace:    at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
>   message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst,
>   Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult)    at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode
>   code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
>   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size)    at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)

Is there any chance to see what could be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Adding this call before request helped me:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

So if you are using https try to change the default SecurityProtocol.

Comment: This just saved my day.. apparently there are still websites out there running on SSL2.0.

Comment: Not working for me. My settings are just like this but no help:  System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls | (SecurityProtocolType)768/*TLS1.1*/ | (SecurityProtocolType)3072/*TLS1.2*/;

Comment: Maybe you could try this:
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3| SecurityProtocolType.Tls| SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Answer (score 12):

Another potential cause of this - if you are running on Windows Server 2003 it supports only SSL 2.0, SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0. All of these protocols are now recommended to be disabled in light of recent exploits that have been found for these protocols, so you may find that a tightly secured server just can't be connected to from windows server 2003 whereas it will be fine from your development machine. There's nothing you can really do about this situation other than ask the destination server administrator's team to allow TLS1.0, or upgrade your production server.

Source of SSL support on Win2k3Server: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2011/10/02/support-for-ssl-tls-protocols-on-windows.aspx

Comment: You sir are a genius and I owe you a beer.  Thanks!

Comment: You ever bought that beer?

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

I have put that line before creating the web request.

Comment: I had to use the solution here to get Tls12 working: https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Received-an-unexpected-EOF-or-0-bytes-from-the-transport-stream/td-p/59510

Answer (score 2):

My experienced is just as elRobbo described.  I have to upgrade the Win2k3 server to Win2k8.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
```

is only supported in .net 4.5, which is not supported in Win2k3...

Answer (score 1):

I received a similar error, ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, resolved it by switching the ordering of my
applicationUrl value in launchSettings.json

Originally was receiving:

```
System.IO.IOException: ' Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.'
```

Apparently bad ordering? **(Note https:// before http://)**

```
"profiles": {
"MyWebApi": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "swagger",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },  
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:50801;http://localhost:50800"

 }
}
```

Changing the order of the URL's fixed the issue, at least in my case **(Note http:// before https://)**

```
"profiles": {
"MyWebApi": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "swagger",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },  
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:50800;https://localhost:50801"

}
```

}

Simply leaving the https entry also resulted in the described error.

I also cleaned my local certs, that too had no effect

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why (especially since it goes against docs I've seen on the matter) but I've found that leaving out the assignment of `RequestLength`. Rather, just write to the request stream without setting the header.

This also has the advantage that:

```
using(Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stm))
{
  sw.Write(postData);
}
```

is to my mind simpler, along with having greater advantages in cases where the data is larger and written piece by piece, or comes from something like an `XMLWriter` that can be set up to write straight to the stream in question.