# System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest

I'm posting some data to the server but the application is throwing exception. 
Here's the code.

```
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3

        Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        request.Method = "POST"
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length
        request.ContentType = "text/xml"
        Using requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
        End Using
```

Here's the exception stacktrace.

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
```

I've updated my code as per the answer/s [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382548/getting-eof-exception-over-https-call) but to no avail. I've also checked that the proxy server has been disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find that the server that I was `POST`ing to was only accepting requests having security protocol TLS 1.1 and above. The application is running on .NET 3.5 which only supports SSL and TLS 1.0 protocols. The solution will be to upgrade the application to .NET 4.5 and use TLS 1.1 and above to make requests to the HTTP service.